# wrapbootstrap for Java web Application

Tags: css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have downloaded a bootstrap theme from [wrapbootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/) for my Java web application. But I don't know how to start with it. I have already added bootstrap css to my application. But I want to remove that and need to add the new theme.

When I unzipped the file, it has many files - JQuery and CSS. But the CSS files are extending with **.scss**. But there is one **html** folder. Inside that there are many bootstrap and other CSS and example html files also. In the html files, it including all the CSS it is using. So do I need to import like that in my JSP files?

This is the html example file from the theme.

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Flatty - Flat Administration Template</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
    <meta content='Flat administration template for Twitter Bootstrap.' name='description'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='57x57'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='72x72'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='114x114'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='144x144'>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/javascripts/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- / bootstrap [required files] -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / jquery ui -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/jquery.ui-1.10.0.custom.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/jquery.ui.1.10.0.ie.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / switch buttons -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/bootstrap_switch/bootstrap-switch.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / xeditable -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/xeditable/bootstrap-editable.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/common/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / wysihtml5 (wysywig) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/common/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / jquery file upload -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/jquery_fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / full calendar -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / select2 -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/select2/select2.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / mention -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/mention/mention.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / tabdrop (responsive tabs) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/tabdrop/tabdrop.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / jgrowl notifications -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / datatables -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/datatables/bootstrap-datatable.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / dynatrees (file trees) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/dynatree/ui.dynatree.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / color picker -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/bootstrap_colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / datetime picker -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/bootstrap_datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / daterange picker) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/bootstrap_daterangepicker/bootstrap-daterangepicker.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / flags (country flags) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/flags/flags.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / slider nav (address book) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/slider_nav/slidernav.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / fuelux (wizard) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/plugins/fuelux/wizard.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / theme files [required files] -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/light-theme.css" media="all" id="color-settings-body-color" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/theme-colors.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/demo.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
```

And in each other pages it has similar imports. In my JSP also do I need to import like this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

The problem is I am using struts2 web application. There I added a filter to process each request. There I wanted to ignore al the js, css, and font types. Now it's working